# Task order in Cardwall

Tags: tuleap

I'm using tuleap version 10.

In my project I have an user story with several tasks in it, this tasks need to be done in a specific order, however this order doesn't match the order by wich they were created in the backlog. So, in sprint overview I've reorder them by priority this lead to the artifact ids to became in a non numeric order.

I was conviced that this was the right way to do it but in cardwall view they still show in numeric order by artifact id. In the sprint planning they still show in the order I pretend.

Am I wrong in the assuption that the order in cardwall view should match the order in planning?

Is there any configuration that will change the task order in cardwall?

What can I do to fix this?

Thanks for all the help.